# Loading text in index html angular 2

Tags: angular

I am new in angular 2. In angular 2 project generated by angular-cli, i saw the following code in `index.html` file but it seems that the word loading is not shown.

```
<app-root>Loading ...</app-root>
```

My question is:
1) What is the purpose of having the Loading text in between `<app-root>`? 
2) When will the word loading be shown? 
3) How can i force the loading text to be shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE**: Not tried with **CLI** but this should work.

**1 & 2)** 
**Purpose** of ***Loding.. text*** is: if, for some reason, it takes some time(due to slow network or some other reason) to load or initiate or bootstrap the app, it will show ***Loading... text***

Do you have **main.ts** file? 
or somewhere you have `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)` line where you bootstrap **mainmodule/appmodule**. Just wrap it around **setInterval()** then you'll be able to see **loading...** text

**3)** **Forcefully showing it**

```
setInterval(()=>{
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);  
},10000)
```

**DEMO (with core angular2 app -NOT Angular-CLI)** : in there look for main.ts file.
 **https://plnkr.co/edit/oiT4L79c21EP2MQXq0oM?p=preview**

Answer (score 0):

is unknown tag to browser unless it is compiled.. so it will show the loading text untill the root compenent is compiled, once it is compiled it will replace the inner content with it's compiled content.